# Смена языка раскладки клавиатуры коммандой Bash в Linux terminal

Tags: bash, консоль

Хочу, чтобы при запуске терминала автоматически включалась английская раскладка.Соответственно мне для этого нужна команда, чтобы она выполнялась при запуске терминала. Нашёл [такой](https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/15874351%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B%D1%8B)(setxkbmap us) способ, но в терминале остаётся русская(хотя в остальных окнах английская), но самое плохое, что она потом не переключается обратно даже через настройки.
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: `setxkbmap -layout us,ru` ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не работает

Comment: Такой вариант: создать команду для выбора конкретного языка и выполнять её после старта терминала. У вас gnome?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy да

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176703/switch-between-keyboard-languages-by-cli-in-gnome

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0`, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1`. У меня работает.

Comment: Просто не ставьте русскую локлизацию при установке системы

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy этот вариант тоже не работает